# null check error on textformfield flutter

Tags: forms, dart-null-safety, flutter-textformfield

This is ridiculous :D one form works fine, the other form with the exact same textFormFields, but different formsKey and different methods gives error:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27244): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive 
InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27244): getTextAfterCursor on inactive 
InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27244): getSelectedText on inactive 
InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27244): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive 
InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27244): getTextAfterCursor on inactive 
InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27244): getSelectedText on inactive 
InputConnection
I/flutter (27244): Null check operator used on a null value
```

My flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 
 10.0.22000.434], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 
version 31.0.0-rc5)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
 [√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 
16.10.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
```

• No issues found!

the working form is for login in:

```
 buildForm(BuildContext context, LoginViewModel viewModel) {
 return Form(
  key: viewModel.formsKey,
  child: Center(child:
    Column(
    children: [
      const SizedBox(
        height: 24,
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
      TextFormField(
        autofocus: true,
        enabled: !viewModel.loading,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: 
  BorderSide(color: Color(0xffdc9b7d))),
          icon: Icon(Icons.email_outlined, color: Color(0xffdc9b7d)),
          focusColor: Color(0xffdc9b7d), fillColor: Color(0xffdc9b7d),
        ),
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        validator: validateEmail,
        onEditingComplete: (){
          setState(() {
          email = emailController.text.trim();
            viewModel.setEmail(email);
          });
        },
        focusNode: viewModel.emailFN,
        controller: emailController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
      TextFormField(
        autofocus: true,
        enabled: !viewModel.loading,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: 
  BorderSide(color: Color(0xffdc9b7d))),
          icon: Icon(Icons.password_outlined, color: 
  Color(0xffdc9b7d)),
            focusColor: Color(0xffdc9b7d), fillColor: 
  Color(0xffdc9b7d),

        ),
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        validator: validatePassword,
        onFieldSubmitted: (String val) => viewModel.login(context),
        obscureText: true,
        onEditingComplete: (){
          password = passController.text.trim();
          viewModel.setPassword(password);
        },
        focusNode: viewModel.passFN,
        controller: passController,
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, top: 10),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => viewModel.forgotPassword(context),
            child: Text(
                  Languages.of(context)!.passwordForgot,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),

              ),
            ),
          ),
      const SizedBox(height: 50.0),
      SizedBox(
        height: 45.0,
        width: 180.0,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: Constants.style,
          child: Text(
            Languages.of(context)!.login.toUpperCase(),
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () async {
            viewModel.login(context);
          }
        ),
      ),
    ]),
  ));
}
```

it authenticates and logs in user, it fires the warning on inputInactive, but still works!

the form that does not work and fires the Null value is the editing personal data form:

```
buildForm(EditProfileViewModel viewModel, BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
  child: Form(
    key: viewModel.formsKey1,
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 15.0,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined,
                color:  Color(0xffdc9b7d)),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        Expanded(
            child: TextFormField(
          cursorColor: Constants.mainColor,
          autofocus: true,
             enabled: !viewModel.loading,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffdc9b7d))),
              focusColor: const Color(0xffdc9b7d),
              fillColor: const Color(0xffdc9b7d),
          hintText: Languages.of(context)!.username),
          focusNode: viewModel.usernameFN,
              controller: usernameController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
validator: validateName,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              onEditingComplete: (){
            setState(() {
              username = usernameController.text.trim();
              viewModel.setUsername(username);
            });
          },
            ))],
    ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10.0,
        ),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Icon(Icons.email_outlined,
            color:  Color(0xffdc9b7d)),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        Expanded(
          child: TextFormField(
          autofocus: true,
          cursorColor: Constants.mainColor,
          enabled: !viewModel.loading,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffdc9b7d))),
              focusColor: const Color(0xffdc9b7d),
              fillColor: const Color(0xffdc9b7d),
              hintText: Languages.of(context)!.email),
          focusNode: viewModel.emailFN,
          validator: validateEmail,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          controller: emailController,
          onFieldSubmitted: (String val) => viewModel.editProfile(context),
            onEditingComplete: (){
            setState(() {
               email=emailController.text.trim() ;
              viewModel.setEmail(email);
            });
          },
        )
)
      ]),
        const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget> [
              ElevatedButton(
                style: Constants.style,
                onPressed: () async {
                  viewModel.editProfile(context);
                },
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    Languages.of(context)!.save,
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),)
            ]
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

for authentication and user profile i use firestore. I am testing on a real device Motorola p30 note.

I tried everything! different onSaved, onChange and onEditingComplete methods. Still returns null.

the update profile methods are:

```
editProfile(BuildContext context) async {
FormState? form = formsKey1.currentState;
if (form!=null) {
  form.save();
if (!form.validate()) {
  validate = true;
  notifyListeners();
  showInSnackBar(context, Languages.of(context)!.errorEditPro);
} else {
  try {
    loading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    bool success = await userService.updateProfile(
        file: image!,
        username: username,
        email: email);
    if (success) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const InputUserData()));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    loading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    debugPrint(e.toString());
  }
  loading = false;
  notifyListeners();
}}
```

}

and then:

```
updateProfile({
required Uint8List file,
required String username,
required String email
}) async {
String res = "Some error Occurred";
try {
    String photoUrl =
    await uploadImage('profilePic', file, false);

    UserModel _user = UserModel(
      username: username,
      id: currentUserId(),
      photoUrl: photoUrl,
      email: email
    );

    await usersRef
        .doc(currentUserId())
        .update(_user.toJson());
    res = "success";
} catch (err) {
  return err.toString();
}
return res;
```

}

please, help! I dont know where is the issue and what to do? stuck here for days!! thanks!